# How to disable wysiwyg editor for body field in PyroCMS 2.x?

Tags: pyrocms

I would like to disable the CK Wysiwyg editor in PyroCMS 2.x so that I can enter plain HTML code without switching each time to the source view. Is this possible and how can I it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version you have, you can do the following:

- Go to the Pages modules and open the "page types" section
- create a new page type (klick on button on the top right)
- set up you're page type by giving it a proper name (e. g. HTML Default)
  and make sure it uses the correct theme layout
- open the "Layout" tab and insert `{{ html_body }}`
- click "Save"

In the next window, you'll have to add a field to your new page type

- Click "+ New Field" in the upper right corne
- Choose "HTML Body" as the name and make sure, that the slug is set to "html_body"
- set the field to "required"
- choose the "Textarea"
- set "Content Type" to "HTML"
- click "Save"

You're now set up to use your new page type "HTML Default".

Choose this page type when adding a new page, and you'll be getting a simple textarea instead of a WYSIWYG editor.